# Router.Navigate from Angular Library Doesn't Work

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, router

I have an Angular workspace where I build and compile 5 packages. I then install those packages on a separate project. When referencing these builds within the same workspace. This works no problem. However, after I pack and publish and install on a new project it no longer works.

I have narrowed the code down to this try catch. No errors are throw, no navigation is performed.

This code is in my component inside my library.

```js
try {
            await this._oidcService.handleCallback();
            const url = sessionStorage.getItem('redirectUrl') ?? '';
            sessionStorage.removeItem('redirectUrl');

            this._router.navigate([url]).then(success => {
                console.log("Navigation successful:", success)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error("Navigation Error: ", error);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error handling sign-in callback:', error);

            // Handle errors, e.g., show a message, log out, navigate to an error page, etc
            this._router.navigate(['/error'], { queryParams: { error: 'Sign-in callback error' } })
        }
```

Neither Navigation Successful or the Navigation Error gets triggered. But I can see the session storage is updating and removing the redirect url.

I have attempted to add "preserveSymlinks": true
with no difference.

I have logged the Navigation Start/End/Error/Cancel. Nothing indicating that the router is trying to change.

The strangest part is that it works within my library workspace. I have a sandbox application set up to use the dist folder.

Is anyone able to assist me on this matter? Is this even a feature that is allowed, router navigating from a library?

Comment: This may happen if the instance of router in the library is not the same as in the app, it is really hard to get to this situation with the latest versions of Angular, but it is hard to say for sure based on the information you provided. What version of angular do you use? Do you have `bundledDependencies` specified for your lib?